# When using StreamReader the file isn't read

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, streamreader

When I use StreamReader` for some reason the file I use isn't read. can I get any help?

[image]

I tried deleting the file and putting it in again but it didn't work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. Please do not share code as images, code is text - so share it as one.

Answer (score 1):

`line` is initialized to `""`, so the `while` loop is never entered. The condition should be `line != null`, not `line == null` like you currently have.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop condition is not correct it should be `while(line != null)`, first of all `line` is initialized to empty string (`""`) so with current code the loop is never entered, secondary `line = b.ReadLine();` should not be `null` until the file ends - from the [`StreamReader.ReadLine` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=net-7.0):

> **Returns** `String`
> The next line from the input stream, or `null` if the end of the input stream is reached.

Also this makes inner check `if(line != null)` obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` is not correct; just have a look:

```
...
string line = "";

// line is NOT null (it's empty) that's why
// while will not enter at all
while (line == null) 
{
...
}
```

Let's change `while` into `for`, let pesky `line` (which is declared out of loop, is check in `while`, in `if` etc.) be a loop variable:

```
// Wrap IDisposable into using; do not Close them expplicitly
using (StreamReader b = new StreamReader("students.txt")) 
{
    ...
    for (string line = b.ReadLine(); line != null; line = b.ReadLine()) 
    {
        if (line == "2") { num2++; }
    ...
    }
    ...
}
```